# How to return a list foreign key fields in a raw form using SerializerMethodField in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey("Author")
  title = models.CharField()
  subtitle = models.CharField()

  def get_full_title(self):
        return "{title}: {subtitle}.".format(title=self.title, subtitle=self.subtitle)
```

Queryset:

```
queryset = Author.prefetch_related("book_set").all()
```

Desired Responce:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "books": [
            "The Hobbit: or There and Back Again",
            "The Fellowship of the Ring: being the first part of The Lord of the Rings.",
            "The Two Towers: being the second part of The Lord of the Rings.",
            "The Return of the King: being the third part of The Lord of the Rings."
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Peter Thiel",
        "books": [
            "The Diversity Myth: Multiculturalism and Political Intolerance on Campus.",
            "Zero to One: Notes on Startups, or How to Build the Future."
        ]
    }
]
```

The problem here is that if you use `serializers.ListSerializer()` on `Authors.book_set` list, I will get an entire model in that list with all it's fields.

If you try to use `serializers.SerializerMethodField`, DRF would not let you use it on multiple results. SerializerMethodField doesn't support an option many AKA `serializers.SerializerMethodField(many=True)`
*I should note here that one could write a method that cycles through the results and accumulates them into a string, but that limits you from further extending this piece of code.*

**P.S.** I'm posting this question as a reference, since I couldn't find an answer anywhere else. Check the answer below for more details.

**P.P.S.** I know that Tolkien wrote more than 4 books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you  need to create a custom list serializer with a method that will return a string with needed representation.

```
class AutorBookSetSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def get_custom_repr(self, obj):
        return obj.get_full_title()
```

Second, you need to crate your regular model serializer with a new field `"books"` that is not present in your initial model. Then you assign your new serializer to this field and as a child you can specify your custom `SerializerMethodField` call.

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    books = AutorBookSetSerializer(child=serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_custom_repr'))

    class Meta:
        model = Author

        fields = [
            "id",
            "name",
            "books",
        ]
```

**Q:** Why would anyone possibly ever need this?

**A:** If `"title"` field was something more complex, like a foreign key, where you  would only want to get the value itself and not fetch the entire model, you could use this structure to define that logic inside of `get_custom_repr` method.